# Jbox2d LiquidFun particle speed

Tags: java, jbox2d, liquidfun

Using JBox2D with LiquidFun my water particles are functioning fine with the exception that they travel at very slow velocities. I can't seem to find a way to get the particles to fall faster. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't updated to 1.0 of LiquidFun yet, which I think increases the speed of the particles.  You might want to look at some of the constants.  Also, you can always decrease the size of all of your objects, which will make the speed limit effectively faster.

Comment: Great work with jBox2d by the way. I believe in the c++ version of liquid fun, the World.step() function has a particle iteration parameter. This may do it. Was wondering how difficult do you think it would be to add it?